# Does extension messaging like chrome.runtime.sendMessage internally use JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> A message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object)

The chrome extension specification indicates that message passed between background and content script can be a Javascript object, which means that we can pass a Javascript object without using JSON.stringify. Does that mean Chrome internally execute JSON.stringify before sending messages? If not, is there a performance gain if I just pass Javascript object without JSONification?

Comment: They probably use HTML5 Structured Cloning, which is more efficient and flexible than JSON ([mentioned in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10916838/1114)). There will probably be a *tiny* performance gain by doing this, instead of manually JSONifying.

Comment: Considering that the APIs are implemented in the native code, it's probably serialized natively in V8. Note that it's _different_ from `JSON.stringify` serialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In Chrome** the messages are automatically JSON-serialized (literally using `JSON.stringify`) in Chrome's JavaScript shim layer that interacts with an extension as can be seen in the [source code of messaging.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/resources/messaging.js?q=runtime.sendmessage&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=69).

The same applies to chrome.runtime.sendMessage and chrome.tabs.sendMessage which use `Port`-based messaging internally.

It means that only JSON-compatible portion of the object is passed: strings, numbers, booleans, null, and objects/arrays that consist of the listed types. Complex types are not supported and will be sent as an empty object `{}` e.g. DOM elements, Set, Map, class instances, functions, and so on.

**To send an unsupported type**, serialize/stringify it manually, for example if `map = new Map()`:

- `{data: [...map]}` when sending
- `new Map(request.data)` when receiving

Hopefully, Chrome will be able to send more types directly one day, see https://crbug.com/248548.

**In Firefox**, the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) is used, which preserves many popular complex types like Date, RegExp, Blob, File, ArrayBuffer, Map, Set, and several others.

Comment: Does anyone know if theres an update on this? Stringify seems like a pretty broken way of sending large files between contexts, since the `chrome://` protocol is secure, right? In my specific case, I have a content script running on a `file://` protocol, so it doesn't have server 'cors' privileges that are often necessary. If I am to parse a pdf, I have to serialize 80MB into JSON 

Comment: Nothing's changed. The best way to transfer large data from the content script context into extension context is a web_accessible_resources iframe, [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689866).