# Chrome Extension - Sending variable from content script to event page

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want an event page to get a variable from the content script that sends it a message. As far as I know, I can only send a simple JSON message to the event page, such as `{greeting: "hello"}`.

How can I send a variable from the content script to the event page?

I've looked into `JSON.stringify()` to send the variable through the JSON message but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: What's in the variable?

Comment: @gcampbell a string.

Comment: You should be able to encode it as JSON. What's not working with `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a variable named `VAR`, you could directly send it via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` without doing anything, because [the message is automatically JSON-serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234925/does-chrome-extension-internally-use-json-stiringify-to-postmessage-over-to-back).

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: VAR });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass stringify your object when sending the message from your content script and then parse it in your event page when you receive it.

Content Script

```
var myObj = {};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: myObj}, function(response) {

});
```

Event Page

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      var data = request.data;
});
```

Comment: [the message is automatically JSON-serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234925/does-chrome-extension-internally-use-json-stiringify-to-postmessage-over-to-back)