# Accessing background script object from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to access background script objects form a content script inside chrome extension?

In content script I have:

```
    // this will store settings
    var settings = {};

    // load settings from background
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        name: "get-settings"
    }, function(response) {
        debugger;
        settings = response.data.settings;
    });
```

Inside the background script I have:

```
    var Settings = function() {
    var me = this;
    // internal, default
    var settingList = {
        serverUrl : "http://automatyka-pl.p4",
        isRecordingEnabled : true,
        isScanEnabled : true
    };

    this.get = function( key ) {
        return settingList[key];
    };
    this.set = function( key , value ) {
        if (settingList[key] != value) {
            var setting = {};
            setting[key] = value;

            chrome.storage.sync.set(setting, function() {
                settingList[key] = value;
            });
        }
        return true;
    };

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.name == 'get-settings') {
        sendResponse({
            data : {
                settings : settings
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
});

var settings = new Settings();
```

Messaging works, i mean response is send but returned object is empty. Do you know how to solve that?

**EDIT**
Based on your comments and answer will try to add different light to my question.

The actual problem is: 
**How to access background "model" from content script**.

Lets assume that *content script* continuously responds to page DOM changes. Any time changes are detected some processing is made inside *content script*. But this processing is depended on extension setting. Those setting can be set via page *action popup script* which informs *background model* what those settings are.

So, any time page is processed with *content script* it should be aware of **current** settings stored inside *background script*.

As already described pulling settings from background is an asynchronous process, so i need a callback for further processing inside content script. Further processing must wait for settings (so this should be handled synchronously?).

It's hard for my to imagine what program flow should look like in this case.

1. background loads (setting initialized)
2. page loads -> content script loads
3. content script requests settings -> further processing is done inside callback function.
4. user changes setting, background settings are changed
5. page change is triggered and content script responds
6. content script requests settings -> further processing is done inside callback function - but it cannot be the same function like in pt. 3 (content "model" does not have to be initialized)?

Comment: All chrome.* API with function callbacks is asynchronous. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: got it! it seems i have to reorganize the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: re: #6 just use another callback if needed, yeah.

Comment: Example added to answer below. You must use another callback to receive changed settings in your content-script. Because of your settings in content-script saved in global property - it will be visible in all contexts in content-script (even in your first callback) where it is not redefined by local settings. There is no universal way to direct access another context's models because of security reasons.

Comment: Guys! Thanks for your involvement! Your explanations helped solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. sendMessage doesn't transfer the object itself, but only its JSON-ifiable representation, 
   effectively [`objReceived = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objSent))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234925/does-chrome-extension-internally-use-json-stiringify-to-postmessage-over-to-back), so since your object's `settingList` is invisible outside function context it's lost during serialization.

   You can make it public by exposing a stringifiable property

   ```js
   this.settingList = { foo: 'bar' };
   ```

   that would be transferred to your content script successfully.
2. Since messaging is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), to use the response in the content script you should do it inside the response callback:

   ```js
   // this will store the settings
   var settings = {};

   // load settings from background
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
       name: "get-settings"
   }, function(response) {
       settings = response.data.settings;
       onSettingsReady();
   }); 

   function onSettingsReady() {
      // put your logic here, settings are set at this point
   }
   ```
3. To know if settings changed outside your content-script, in settings setter in background.js send messages to your tab's content-script:

   ```js
   this.set = function( key , value ) {
       ...
       // notify active tab if settings changed
       chrome.tabs.query({"windowType":"normal"}, function(tabs){
       for( id in tabs ){
           if("id" in tabs[id]){
               chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[id].id,{"action":"update-settings","settings":settings});
           }
       }
   });
       return true;
   };
   ```
4. And in content-script listen and process this message:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
       if("action" in msg && msg.action == 'update-settings'){
           // You are setting global settings variable, so on it will be visible in another functions too
           settings = msg.settings;
       }
   });
   ```

More details: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage.

P.S. Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` instead of `chrome.extension.sendMessage` as the latter is deprecated in Chrome API and totally unsupported in WebExtensions API (Firefox/Edge).

Comment: Well, i've made `settingList` public, and indeed it is props can be serialized and retrived back in content script. But anyway because of asynchronous nature of `sendMessage` they settings object inside content script is not initialized before it is needed.

Comment: Use callback from your message receiver, like `settings=response.data.settings; ready();` And run other code inside it, like you do inside `document.ready` callback. This is problem not listed in your question example.

Comment: And about your second question - just use another callback to receive settings and set global variable settings on it, it would be accessible inside your first callback.

Comment: Or attach full usecase of your content-script, will try to help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much! I've came to quite same conclusions on friday and reorganized code similar to your answer. The difference is that i'm pulling settings from background when content script fires, and have another listener on DOM initialization. In this listner i'm checking both conditions (DOM init, settings init) inside setInterval loop. When those conditions are met, I'm doing further processing.

Comment: Glad to help you! :) setInterval is a variant too, but is gives a bit more CPU usage

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to have another instance of `Settings` in your content script.

After all, `chrome.storage` API is available in content scripts.

Of course, you need to watch for changes made in other parts of the extension - but you should be doing so anyway, since you're using `chrome.storage.sync` and its value can change independently by Chrome Sync.

So, proposed solution:

1. Add a listener to [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) and process changes to update your `settingList` as needed.
2. Move the `Storage` logic to a separate JS "library", e.g. `storage.js`
3. Load `storage.js` in your content script and use it normally.

You may also want to adjust your storage logic so that saved data is *actually* taken into account - right now it's always the default. You can do something like this:

```
var defaultSettingList = {
    serverUrl : "http://automatyka-pl.p4",
    isRecordingEnabled : true,
    isScanEnabled : true
};
var settingList = Object.assign({}, defaultSettingList);
chrome.storage.sync.get(defaultSettingList, function(data) {
  settingList = Object.assign(settingList, data);
  // At this point you probably should call the "ready" callback - initial
  //   load has to be async, no way around it
});
```