# Using postMessage to extension background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postmessage, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to send a `CryptoKey` (generated by `SubtleCrypto.generateKey()`) object from a contentscript to the background page of a webextension.

When using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send the object, it is lost, as `CryptoKey` is not stringifyable (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234925/does-chrome-extension-internally-use-json-stiringify-t)). Using `window.postMessage` to transfer the key to another **window** does work, as this method uses structured cloning..

Is there something similar to `postMessage` to send data that is not stringifyable to the background page of a webextension?

Comment: The only workaround is to create an iframe in the content script, pointing to an html file inside the extension (exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)), postMessage the key there. Inside the iframe you can either directly invoke a global method from the background script via chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage or use BroadcastChannel API).

Comment: That way the key is only available when the user has the page containing it open . Sadly this is not an option. (Edit: I think I misunderstood you at first. I'm going to try that)

Comment: @wOxxOm really cool, it works. If you post this as answer, I'm happy to accept it :)

Comment: If you post an answer with the actual code it'd be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @wOxxOm I solved it by creating a web accessible resource with this code:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().postMessage(event.data, "*");
}
```

This is triggered by the contentscript like that:

```
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('webaccessible/index.html'));
iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
  iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(data);
})
```

While data is an object that contains the `CryptoKey`.

This data is received in the background script just like you normally would receive such messages:

```
window.addEventListener('message',(event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```