# Transferring ImageData to background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Studying extensions for Google Chrome

I get data from a video camera, draw it on `canvas`, then get `ImageData` from canvas and send it to `service_worker` for further processing. As a connection, I use a long-lived port between content and service_worker.

Here is my code:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'myPort'});  // <--- opening the port
function run(){

    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);

    let data = Array.from(imageData.data);  // <--- 30ms - 40ms

    port.postMessage({message: 'video_frame', data: data});  // <--- 40ms - 100ms
};
```

The main problem is that the sending operation takes a very long time (from 80ms - 140 ms), but at the same time I cannot refuse to send data to service_worker.

Is there a way to speed up data transfer somehow?

Comment: Use a web_accessible_resources iframe, see [two-way MessagePort example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689866).