# Chrome Extension: how to get element of an iframe with extension file in a content script?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension creates an iframe with an HTML file included in the extension on each web page. I would like to access and modify values of elements in the iframe, but the `contentDocument` attribute of the iframe object is null.

Here are the files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "iframe example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "iframe",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    { "resources": [ "foo.html" ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>" ]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
(function() {
    const frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.id = 'foo';
    frame.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('foo.html');
    frame.style.width = '100px';
    frame.style.height = '100px';
    frame.style.position = 'fixed';
    frame.style.zIndex = '99999';
    frame.style.top = '0';
    frame.style.left = '0';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
})();


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.code === 'KeyY') {
    frame = document.getElementById('foo');
    console.log(frame.contentDocument.getElementById('foo'));
  }
});
```

**foo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="foo">WAITING</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementById')
```

Of course the iframe is fully loaded when I press the keys.

The error is likely due to the web page and the HTML files not being from the same origin. How to resolve the issue? In real case, I need access both to the web page and the iframe as I'd like to extract some content of the web page, transform it and set the value of a `div` object in the iframe.

Comment: It's a cross-origin iframe, you can't modify it directly. Add `<script src=foo.js></script>` to foo.html and use `document` in foo.js which will run inside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks, but in real case I'd like to extract some content of the webpage, transform it and set the value of a `div` element in the iframe.

Comment: Use messages: [Communication between content script and web\_accessible\_resources iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689866).